# Computation of a limit involving factorial $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n+1] {(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n] {(n)!} = \frac{1}{e}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, factorial, radicals

I want to prove the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n+1\;] {(n+1)!} - \sqrt[n] {(n)!} = \frac{1}{e}.$$

I searched the forum & found the link here: [If $\frac{p_{n+1}}{np_n} \to p > 0 $, then $\sqrt[n+1]{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt[n]{p_{n}} \to \frac{p}{e}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457308/if-fracp-n1np-n-to-p-0-then-sqrtn1p-n1-sqrtnp-n) .

But still, there is no way out of the problem. So, please solve it.

Comment: you could also apply stirlings approximation

Comment: It is easy to show that if the limit exists it must be equal to $1/e$. The hard part is showing that the limit exists.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Evaluate the limit. If you find a finite answer, then it exists !!! Don't go for the difficult path.

Comment: @FelixMarin: I agree that most of the times existence of limit is proved by evaluating it (following various theorems on limits). But in this case the evaluation of limit is not easy. But I repeat it is easy to show that if this limit exists then it must be $1/e$ (by using Cesaro Stolz theorem).

Comment: See also: [Limit of the sequence $a_n=\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020153)

Answer (score 8):

Hint:  Set $p_n = n!$.

Then what is
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{p_{n+1}}{np_n}?$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : The limit you have mentioned is clearly is $1$ . But how it would help me??? ... I didn't know about that "Sterling Approximation"... I want to compute the limit without using that!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write the expression $a(n) = e^{\log a_n}$, then you can use the bonds on $\int_{1}^{n} \log x dx < \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k < 1+ \int_{1}^{n} \log x dx$ to get the asymptotic result.

Comment: I am looking for a method without using Integral... isn't there any solution using more elementary tools??

Answer (score 1):

It appears (after looking at several other answers posted here) that it is difficult to avoid the use of Stirling's approximation. Stirling's approximation is given by $$\log n! = n\log\left(\frac{n}{e}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi n) + \frac{1}{12n} + O(n^{-2})$$ and hence $$\log (n!)^{1/n} = \log\left(\frac{n}{e}\right) + \frac{\log (2\pi n)}{2n} + O(n^{-2})$$ and therefore $$(n!)^{1/n} = \exp\left(\log\left(\frac{n}{e}\right) + \frac{\log (2\pi n)}{2n} + O(n^{-2})\right) = \frac{n}{e}\exp\left(\frac{\log (2\pi n)}{2n} + O(n^{-2})\right)$$ and thus we get $$(n!)^{1/n} = \frac{n}{e}\left(1 + \frac{\log (2\pi n)}{2n} + O(n^{-2}(\log n)^{2})\right)$$ or $$(n!)^{1/n} = \frac{n}{e} + \frac{\log(2\pi n)}{2e} + O(n^{-1}(\log n)^{2})$$ and then using the above formula for $((n + 1)!)^{1/(n + 1)}$ and on subtracting we get $$\sqrt[n + 1]{(n + 1)!} - \sqrt[n]{n!} = \frac{1}{e} + \frac{1}{2e}\log\left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right) + O(n^{-1}(\log n)^{2}) $$ and the result follows by taking limit as $n \to \infty$.

---

I later checked the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457308/72031) and found that the result in that question crucially depends on the limit in this question and hence the problem in current question is the more fundamental one and its genuine answer can not be based on the answer of the linked question. Also the linked question has an excellent answer by Daniel Fischer which uses the Stirling's approximation to obtain a limit which is same as the one in current question.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @martycohen: thanks for the concern. Nowadays it has become fashionable to vote without any comment and i have been the victim many times. If you can see other (deleted) answers of this question, I have downvoted with comment and the people have then deleted their post. That is the way downvotes help. I wonder what's the benefit of downvoting without comment.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh (+1) I think this is the only helpful answer in this posting.

Answer (score 0):

By Stolz-Cesaro theorem , we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$$

and by the root-to-ratio limit, we also have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\times\frac{n^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$

which, by the limit definition of $e$, is given by

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}=\frac1e$$

Comment: This argument requires proving first that the limit exists.