# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-((n)!)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find $\lim_{n\to
>  \infty}((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-((n)!)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$

We need to deal the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(1)+\log(2)+...+\log(n)}{n}$. We know that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \log(n)=\infty \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(1)+\log(2)+...+\log(n)}{n}=\infty$(since, By Cauchy's first theorem on limit). Hence we get $\infty-\infty$. How do I show that there exists finite limit?

Comment: Let me check. But the limit is infinity.

Comment: The limit should be $1/e$.

Comment: How do we get?Can you give some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using Stirling's Formula we have

$$\begin{align}
\left((n+1)!\right)^{1/(n+1)}-\left(n!\right)^{1/n}&=\left(\left(\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}\left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n+1}\right)\left(1+O(1/n)\right)\right)^{1/(n+1)}\\\\
&-\left(\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\right)\left(1+O(1/n)\right)\right)^{1/n}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

---

> Alternatively, I provided a different, less "brute force" approach in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020153/limit-of-the-sequence-a-n-sqrtn1n1-sqrtnn).

Comment: This it is not convincing at all. Did you really check that this gets somewhere ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy First of all, it is a HINT only.  And yes, I did check this and found that the limit is simply $1/e$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Alternatively, I provided a different, less "brute force" approach in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020153/limit-of-the-sequence-a-n-sqrtn1n1-sqrtnn).

Comment: Is your sirling formula correct? $\sqrt{2 \pi n}$ in the numerator?

Comment: your alternate approach is very excellent :)

Comment: @Unknownx I've corrected the typographical error.  Thank you for alerting me.

Comment: And pleased you liked the other approach I posted quite a while ago.  ;-)