# Prove: $\lim\limits _{n\rightarrow\infty} \left( ((n+1)!)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} \right)=\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: calculus, limits, cauchy-sequences

I see this solution in a book but I don't understand it.  Which theorems were used?

I know how I solve this limit but this solution in book as following:

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( (n+1) \left(\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-n \left(\frac{n!}{n^n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \right)$$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n = \frac{1}{e}$$

But I don't understand which theorem use it here in the first step?  Is it Alembert?

Comment: You  should need Stirling formula.

Comment: I tell I know how I solve it , I need understand this method .

Comment: PS: This is known as a Lalescu sequence, named after the Romanian mathematician Traian Lalescu.

Comment: Answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020153/limit-of-the-sequence-a-n-sqrtn1n1-sqrtnn)